# Problem with find element to click in a filter button - SELENIUM

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to automate a task in my job with Selenium.
Everything was going fine until I had to click in a filter button.

I tried with `find_element_by_xpath` but it went wrong. (I tried CSS selector and link text and it also went wrong).

Things that I tried:

```
     nav.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn-lg').click()

Error: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn-lg"}
```

```
    nav.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/form/div[1]/button').click()

Error: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/form/div[1]/button"}
```

HTML from the button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" title="Filtros" ng-click="openFilters()" ga-event="" ga-label="open-orders-filters"><span class="uim-filter-count badge">1</span> <i class="icon-filter"></i></button>
```

and

```
<div class="uim-btn-filter uim-filter-checked" ng-class="{ 'uim-filter-checked': filters.getAppliedFilters().length }"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" title="Filtros" ng-click="openFilters()" ga-event="" ga-label="open-orders-filters"><span class="uim-filter-count badge">1</span> <i class="icon-filter"></i></button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@title='Filtros']").click()
```

Comment: Did not work unfortnetly :( The error was NoSuchElementException again

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: Sorry  but I can't because It's a system which needs a login.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Xpath

```
'//button[@ng-click="openFilters()"]'
```

or this

```
'//button[@title="Filtros()"]'
```

or

```
'//button[@title="Filtros()" and (@ng-click="openFilters()")]'
```

In case your element is inside the iframe you need to do something like following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")))
```

I mentioned the iframe here according to it's tag name. Possibly you will need to use some other locator, according to the actual locator suitable in your case.

Comment: Did not work :( The error for the first and secont was NoSuchElementException and for the last one was SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document'

Comment: Maybe you are missing some wait / delay to let the page and the element load completely? Or maybe there is a iframe there? As about the third option i made a mistake there, already fixed, but it the first 2 options didn't work the third will not too.

Comment: Now you said I realized that it's an iframe. Do you know if it's possible we pick the click in this button despite of this?

Comment: Thanks so much you are saving my life. But I don't know how to find that I have to use instead of "iframe" in your example. Where can I find the real tag name that I have to put there?

Comment: It is not here? `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" title="Filtros" ng-click="openFilters()" ga-event="" ga-label="open-orders-filters"><span class="uim-filter-count badge">1</span> <i class="icon-filter"></i></button>`

Comment: No, I see no iframe here. Can you share a link to the web page you are working on? This would make our life much better.